# Memory leaks,  List And Http Request .net

Tags: .net, list, memory-leaks, httpwebrequest

I have a few question about memory leak.

In my winForm app i use a `TabControl` with `WebBrowser` Objects that i dispose without problem.

I need to use many `List<T>` and 1 of them should be static , it uses about 1000 2000 `Strings`(url) and it need to be cleared and updated every 10 mins while the other list should be used with new element to each loop.

Now i used Dot Trace memory to see what cause the memory leaks. It Doesnt tell me which funcion cause it , for `String` it says that cant find PDB mscorilib.dll and for `Byte[] = Source`is not aviable for array.

```
>  39,28% System.Byte [] Count = 22 Size = 615819 HeldCount = 22 HeldSize
>  = 615819 

>  27,06% System.String Count = 6370 Size = 424222 HeldCount = 6370 HeldSize = 424222 

    3,70% System.Object [] Count = 250 Size = 57992 HeldCount = 6206 HeldSize = 377523
```

(the others alive object use 2% 3%)

I read about memory leaks in some question on stackoverlow , and one of many fault is keep a referenced variable for a List ( for exemple).

Now i would understand : if this code cause memory leaks 
1)

```
private void ExampleLeaks()
    {
        List<String> example = new List<String>();
        example.add("foo");
        example.add("bar");
        return example;
    }
```

the solution should be this?

```
Class foo {
             List<String> example = new List<String>();
             private void ExampleLeaks()
              { 
                example.clear();
                example.add("foo");
                example.add("bar");
                return example;
              }
          }
```

2) Now i dont understand what use the `byte[]`. Only byte that i use is in `HttpWebRequest`.  I made some connections to a webServer where i do a  login , store Cookie and each 1 minute use the  `CookieCollection` from login to update data.

I use this method each 1 minute

In main class i initialize `StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();`

```
 public String DoRequestWeb(String urls, String Method, String user, String data, String License, String Action)
                { 
                    Uri url = new Uri(urls);
                    HttpWebRequest _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    _request.Method = Method;
                    _request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                    _request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
                    _request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
                    _request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    _request.UserAgent = "SomeuserAgent";
                    _request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");  
                    string _postData; 
                   _postData = // Do Stuff 
                    byte[] _byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_postData);
                    Debug.WriteLine(_byteArray.Count());

                    _request.ContentLength = _byteArray.Length; 

                    using (Stream _reqStream = _request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        _reqStream.Write(_byteArray, 0, _byteArray.Length);
                        _reqStream.Close();
                    }
                    buf.Clear(); 
                    using (HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        if (HttpStatusCode.OK == _response.StatusCode)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Status code " + _response.StatusCode);
                            using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                            { 
                                char[] buffer = new char[256];
                                int count;
                                Debug.WriteLine("Buffer [] char count "+(buffer.Count()));
                                while ((count = _reader.Read(buffer, 0, 256)) > 0)
                                {
                                    buf.Append(buffer, 0, count);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                      } 
                    return buf.ToString(); 
                }
```

And 3)

Maybe it's the **worst**  Function Ever wrote in the history of the humans but i
dont realize how write it in better way and **maybe** it cause memory leaks too.

*All This list are initialized in the Class*

```
 //response contain a list of 1000 2000 links taken from a 
 //httpwebRequest and take data from XML Document webpage  and parse it into a list

    public List<MainForm.Links> GetListaCiclo(List<Links> response3)
    {                
                    listGoogle.Clear();
                    listYahoo.Clear();
                    listBing.Clear();
                    listOther.Clear();
                    //Other 4        
                    var rnd = new Random();
                    var q = from a in response3.GroupBy(l => new { l.idHost, l.Type })  
                            let col = a.ToList()
                            select col[rnd.Next(0, col.Count)];

                    foreach (Links str in q)
                    {
                        switch (str.idHost)
                        {
                            case 0: 
                                listGoogle.Add(str);
                                break;
                            case 1: 
                                listYahoo.Add(str);
                                break;
                            case 2: 
                                listBing.Add(str);
                                break;
                            case 3 
                                listOther.Add(str);
                                break; 
                            //Other 4 list 
                        } 
                     }

                    var google = listGoogle.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(4);
                    var yahoo = listYahoo.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(2);
                    var Bing = listBing.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(1);
                    var otherSeacher = listOtherSeacher.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(1);
                    //Other same 4  

                    tmp.Clear();
                    tmp = google.Where(h => h != null).ToList();
                    tmp.AddRange(yahoo.Where(h => h != null));
                    tmp.AddRange(bing.Where(h => h != null));
                    tmp.AddRange(other.Where(h => h != null)); 
                    .....other 4     
                    return tmp;
                }
```

**UPDATE :** 
4) What about Pinvoke?

```
 [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
        const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;

        private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42; 
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

        [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

        [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
```

I just call them 1 time at minute. I dont know if this could cause memory Leaks.

Comment: You seem to have come across some bad information regarding memory leaks and memory usage in general. What makes you think your program has memory leaks? What amounts of memory are we talking here?

Comment: Now wait , memory leaks is sure cause after 1 loop the amount of memory allocated is x after loop 2 memory allocated by system is 2x and soon. So there is a memory leaks becouse the program when delete all tabs clean up his memory but allocated memory by system grow up.

Comment: I update the question adding Pinvoke call.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion those System.Byte[] and System.String are just normal live objects, not memory leaks. These obects are managed by the garbage collector and they get deleted as soon as they aren't used by other objects.

private void ExampleLeaks() - your first example is correct.

Possible reason why you miss a lot of memory are objects of other types which need to be disposed and you didn't dispose them. These undisposed objects probably contain inner byte arrays and strings. You should look at HttpRequest/Response objects etc. I am affraid that DotTrace memory listing can't help you here or better said you can't to read it as simple - even when it says "byte[]" you have to look at objects of different types, not just byte[]. because those different objects may have byte[] arrays inside them.

In the fact it probably doesn't matter if those objects are disposable or not. While they are live, they have some other objects inside them, like byte[] arrays and strings.

Comment: I try to dispose all objects. I just use WebBrowser and i dispose them all. What about the first example is correct the cause leaks? And what about the solution to "dont cause" leaks is correct?

Comment: Correct = no memory leaks. You just forgot to define return type List<string> instead of void. But there are no memory leaks in there.

Comment: I'm sure that i have memory leaks somewhere cause after each loop allocated memory by system increase by x amount while the one of my program keep the same for all his life. The hard part is understand where :|

Comment: What about pinvoke? Could they cause a memory leaks? i use some I update my question so u can read them.

Comment: Yes, pinvoke may cause memory leaks. But it depends on what particular system funcions you call, not easy to tell without deep check.